# CSS sticky footer gap between body elements

Tags: html, css

I use `box-sizing: border-box;` for all elements and I want to make a sticky footer, I tried many different methods but it doesn't work. Even if I use `position: relative;` for footer, then when I use approximately `zoom: 33%` there are gap between bottom and footer. Or when he footer `position: absolute;` the `<section>` goes under footer, or in small zoom there are gap between footer and `<section>`. Please somebody, help me.

```css
* {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

html {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
 height: 100%;
 
 background-color: purple;
 border: 4px dotted purple;
}

body {
 position: relative;
 min-height: 100%;
 
 background-color: blue;
 border: 4px dotted lightblue;

 text-align:center;
 color: white;
}

nav {
 background-color: black;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
}

header, #page_1 {
 height: 800px;
 line-height: 800px;
}

header {
 background-color: green;
}

#page_1 {
 background-color: red;
 border: 4px solid yellow;
}

footer {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>...</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
 <nav>Navigation</nav>

 <header>Header</header>
   
 <section id="page_1">Section</section>
 
 <footer>FOOTER</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's `box-sizing` and not `boxing-size`. I change it in the subject and content to avoid confusions on users (maybe someone thinks that's a punch sport...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already tried to use http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ method?

You have to put all of your contents, except footer, inside a div with a class like "wrapper".
Your nav is in fixed position, so you can also keep it outside from the wrapper.
Inside of the wrapper, at the last position you put a div with class "push"

then use this css

```
* {
margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important; /* This line and the next line are not necessary unless you need IE6 support */
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -155px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 155px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```